# Separating build presets from configurations preset

Tags: cmake

My project can be built in Debug configuration, as well as Release configuration. Also I want to build it both on Linux and Windows, which gives us 4 configurations.

Also my project contains multiple presets, let's call them A, B, C...
These presets are distinguished from each other by preprocessor definitions. Thus, there are at least 12 configurations in total.

What is the usual way to deal with such a number of configurations?

I would define a preset (A, B or C) separately from configuration (release, debug), but I don't know, how to do it. If I don't define a field "configurePreset" in a build preset, then the build preset is not visible.

By the way, I am working on Visual Studio Code, and I see that the configuration preset and build preset can be selected independently. Is there a simple way to "unbind" them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This below file is a possible answer (not tested):

```
{
    "version": 2,
    "configurePresets": [
        {
            "name": "base",
            "hidden": true,
            "binaryDir": "${sourceDir}/build/build-${presetName}",
            "cacheVariables": { "CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE": "OFF" }
        },

        {
            "name": "debug",
            "hidden": true,
            "description": "config for all debug configurations",
            "cacheVariables": { "CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE": "Debug" }
        },
        {
            "name": "release",
            "hidden": true,
            "cacheVariables": { "CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE": "Release" }
        },

        {
            "name": "A",
            "inherits": "base",
            "hidden": true,
            "cacheVariables": { "VARIABLE": "AA" }
        },
        {
            "name": "B",
            "inherits": "base",
            "hidden": true,
            "cacheVariables": { "VARIABLE": "BB" }
        },
        {
            "name": "C",
            "inherits": "base",
            "hidden": true,
            "cacheVariables": { "VARIABLE": "CC" }
        },
        

        {
            "name": "A-debug",
            "inherits": [ "A", "debug" ]
        },
        {
            "name": "A-release",
            "inherits": [ "A", "release" ]
        },
        {
            "name": "B-debug",
            "inherits": [ "B", "debug" ]
        },
        {
            "name": "B-release",
            "inherits": [ "B", "release" ]
        },
        {
            "name": "C-debug",
            "inherits": [ "C", "debug" ]
        }
    ]
}
```

First, you define a "base" node with all you global cache variables. I put `CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE` as an example. You may need to switch verbose mode ON or OFF for the whole project.

Then, you define 2 nodes "debug" and "release" with their respective cached variables (`CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE`)

Then, you define you projects node "A", "B", "C" with again, their respective needed variables.

And finally, you create all your needed combinations using "inherits". You inherit some nodes and all its attributes.

Note that I didn't define C-release but only C-debug to highlight that you can do what you want in those presets.

You only need `configurePresets` if your presets are only about defining cache variables. You may need `buildPresets` if you want to specify a target you need to build but that's not what you requested.

Regarding Visual Studio Code, I'm not sure about what you meant by "unbind" them but I have found this link with some information about it. [cmake-preset](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cmake-tools/blob/main/docs/cmake-presets.md)
I guess the only way would be to add the "hidden":true keyword in your cmake preset but that's doesn't seem very handy.

Comment: Wow, thank you! That is not exactly what I needed, but it solves the problem.
Only I've got the warning message "Manually-specified variables were not used by the project"
And indeed, the preprocessor variable "A" seems to be undefined.

Comment: I figured out how to do this
in the CMakePresets,json in the section `"name": "A"` I have to write
`"environment": {"ReleaseType": "A"}`


And then in the CMakeLists.txt:
`add_definitions(-D$ENV{ReleaseType})`

Comment: This looks strange. Usually you pass preprocessor variables to cmake using `cmake -DVARIABLE=AA`. That's why under node name A you can see `"cacheVariables": { "VARIABLE": "AA" }`. Just replace VARIABLE with your correct variable name and AA the content you need to pass. If that's not the ideal way to do it, please edit your initial question and clarify what are you constraints

Comment: Now, it's OK, it's just not working. I tried it just like you proposed.

Comment: Could you clarify what's not working ? Please edit your initial answer providing the error message

Comment: I receive no error message. "cacheVariables" propertie just does not define proprocessor definition. Anyway, I've got the solution, thank you very much!